# NodeJS SQL returning 'Cannot read property 'x' of undefined' in for loop

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I'm trying to run through each post in a MySQL table, get the username, run a separate query in a separate table getting information from that user such as profile img, etc and then put it in JSON.

This work up until I try and add another query in for getting the user information, as then it returns

```
'Cannot read property 'postId' of undefined'
```

I've tried many workarounds to this, but none of them have worked.

Here's my code:

```
var postLocation = req.query.postLocation.replace(regex, escaper);
connection.query("SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE (postLocation = '" + postLocation + "' OR postLocation = 'Global') AND postDeleted = 'no' ORDER BY postId DESC;", function (err1, rows1, fields1) {
  if(err1){
    res.send(err1);
  } else if(!rows1.length){
    res.send('{"rapids": [{"response": "This post does not exist."}]}');
  } else {
    var queryString = "";
    var queryTimes = 0;
    var profileURL = null;
    for(i = 0; i < rows1.length; i++){
      queryTimes++;
      connection.query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE username = '" + rows1[0].postBy + "' ORDER BY postId DESC;", function (err2, rows2, fields2) {
        queryString = queryString + '{"postId": "' + rows1[i].postId + '", "post": "' + rows1[i].post + '", "postBy": "' + rows1[i].postBy + '", "postLikes": ' + rows1[i].postLikes + ', "postByProfileImgURL": "' + rows1[i].postByProfileImgURL + '", "postDate": "' + rows1[i].postDate + '", "postViews": ' + rows1[i].postViews + ', "postDeleted": "' + rows1[i].postDeleted + '"';
        if(queryTimes == rows1.length){
          queryString = queryString + '}';
        } else {
          queryString = queryString + '}, ';
        }
      });
    }
    res.send('{"rapids": [' + queryString + ']}');
  }
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: Bumping because

Answer (score 0):

rows1[i].postId is in a different context there.  You'll have to pass it into the context that your inner query runs in.

```
var postLocation = req.query.postLocation.replace(regex, escaper);
        connection.query("SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE (postLocation = '" + postLocation + "' OR postLocation = 'Global') AND postDeleted = 'no' ORDER BY postId DESC;", function (err1, rows1, fields1) {
        if(err1){
                res.send(err1);
        } else if(!rows1.length){
            res.send('{"rapids": [{"response": "This post does not exist."}]}');

        } else {
            var queryString = "",
                queryTimes = 0,
                profileURL = null;

            for(i = 0; i < rows1.length; i++){
                queryTimes++;

                connection.query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE username = '" + rows1[0].postBy + "' ORDER BY postId DESC;", function (rows1, err2, rows2, fields2) {
                    queryString = queryString + '{"postId": "' + rows1[i].postId + '", "post": "' + rows1[i].post + '", "postBy": "' + rows1[i].postBy + '", "postLikes": ' + rows1[i].postLikes + ', "postByProfileImgURL": "' + rows1[i].postByProfileImgURL + '", "postDate": "' + rows1[i].postDate + '", "postViews": ' + rows1[i].postViews + ', "postDeleted": "' + rows1[i].postDeleted + '"';

                    if(queryTimes == rows1.length){
                        queryString = queryString + '}';

                    } else {
                        queryString = queryString + '}, ';
                    }
                }.bind(this, rows1));
            }

            res.send('{"rapids": [' + queryString + ']}');
        }
    });
```

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: I updated my response.  I'm not 100% certain on the syntax since I haven't used mysql, but I believe that should get you closer.  If you can set a breakpoint in your inner query you'll be able to verify the arguments that the callback function is using.

Comment: Any further suggestions?